# List Iteration in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So i get this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

pointing to this line of code:

```
if snarePattern[i] == '*':
```

whenever I use what I thought was simple Python

```
snarePattern = ['-', '*', '-', '*']
for i in snarePattern:
    if snarePattern[i] == '*':
        ...
```

Is this not allowed? What don't I know?

And also, If anyone knows where I'm going with this code, can you think of an easier way to create and parse simple patterns like this??? I'm new to Python.

Thanks guys

Comment: As far as your second question (can you think of an easier way to create and parse simple patterns like this?), You're going to need to be more specific.  I would advise trying some things and searching stack overflow.  If you don't find anything and are still having trouble, take a look at the FAQ on what makes an on-topic question.  If your question fits, open a new question and ask (providing details about what you're looking for and what you've tried).  We might be able to help you out :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`for i in snarePattern:` goes through each **item** not each index:

```
>>> snarePattern = ['-', '*', '-', '*']
>>> for c in snarePattern:
        print c


-
*
-
*
```

You can change it to

```
for i in range(len(snarePattern)):
```

if you really need it, but it looks like you don't, just check if `c == '*'` for example.

A *better* way to go through indices is

```
for i, c in enumerate(snarePattern):  # i is each index, c is each character
```

Comment: Don't use `range(len())`, `enumerate()` is so much cleaner.

Comment: @g.d.d.c true but in this case I'm just showing how to go through the indices alone, that adds an extra level of confusion to a simple answer, however it's good to note